# How to filter parent json from child's Id in javascript/vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2

So I have this json.

```
{
    "account_owner": "",
    "account_type": "",
    "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_yhHDzQsDSI",
    "business_name": "",
    "sync_block": false,
    "validation": {
        "isError": false,
        "inputList": [],
        "message": ""
    },
    "is_selected": true,
    "contacts": [{
            "con_title": "",
            "con_fName": "",
            "con_lName": "",
            "con_job_title": "",
            "is_selected": true,
            "emails": [{
                "email": "",
                "type": "",
                "primary": false,
                "is_selected": true,
                "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_yhHDzQsDSK",
                "validation": {
                    "isError": false,
                    "inputList": [],
                    "message": "",
                    "is_selected": true
                },
                "checked": false
            }],
            "phones": [{
                "phone": "",
                "type": "",
                "primary": false,
                "is_selected": true,
                "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_uHN38SxJ3s",
                "validation": {
                    "isError": false,
                    "inputList": [],
                    "is_selected": true,
                    "message": ""
                },
                "checked": false
            }],
            "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_hwzB7dIn9v",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "con_title": "",
            "con_fName": "",
            "con_lName": "",
            "con_job_title": "",
            "is_selected": true,
            "emails": [{
                "email": "",
                "type": "",
                "primary": false,
                "is_selected": true,
                "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_yhHDzQsDSx",
                "validation": {
                    "isError": false,
                    "is_selected": true,
                    "inputList": [],
                    "message": ""
                },
                "checked": false
            }],
            "phones": [{
                "phone": "",
                "type": "",
                "primary": false,
                "is_selected": true,
                "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_uHN38SxJ3Y",
                "validation": {
                    "isError": false,
                    "is_selected": true,
                    "inputList": [],
                    "message": ""
                },
                "checked": false
            }],
            "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_hwzB7dIn9x",
            "checked": false
        }
    ]
}
```

you can see that there are two property on every level

1. `nest_uid`
2. `is_selected`

Now I am getting the child element's `nest_uid` , So I need to mark all the `is_selected` as false except the one selected and its **parent**.

For example

if `nest_id = '17_15_1536914882_yhHDzQsDSK'`

**Output**

```
{
    "account_owner": "",
    "account_type": "",
    "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_yhHDzQsDSI",
    "business_name": "",
    "sync_block": false,
    "validation": {
        "isError": false,
        "inputList": [],
        "message": ""
    },
    "is_selected": true,//here
    "contacts": [{
            "con_title": "",
            "con_fName": "",
            "con_lName": "",
            "con_job_title": "",
            "is_selected": true, //here 
            "emails": [{
                "email": "",
                "type": "",
                "primary": false,
                "is_selected": true,
                "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_yhHDzQsDSK", //here
                "validation": {
                    "isError": false,
                    "inputList": [],
                    "message": "",
                    "is_selected": true
                },
                "checked": false
            }],
            "phones": [{
                "phone": "",
                "type": "",
                "primary": false,
                "is_selected": false,
                "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_uHN38SxJ3s",
                "validation": {
                    "isError": false,
                    "inputList": [],
                    "is_selected": true,
                    "message": ""
                },
                "checked": false
            }],
            "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_hwzB7dIn9v",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "con_title": "",
            "con_fName": "",
            "con_lName": "",
            "con_job_title": "",
            "is_selected": false,
            "emails": [{
                "email": "",
                "type": "",
                "primary": false,
                "is_selected": false,
                "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_yhHDzQsDSx",
                "validation": {
                    "isError": false,
                    "is_selected": false,
                    "inputList": [],
                    "message": ""
                },
                "checked": false
            }],
            "phones": [{
                "phone": "",
                "type": "",
                "primary": false,
                "is_selected": false,
                "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_uHN38SxJ3Y",
                "validation": {
                    "isError": false,
                    "is_selected": false,
                    "inputList": [],
                    "message": ""
                },
                "checked": false
            }],
            "nest_uid": "17_15_1536914882_hwzB7dIn9x",
            "checked": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You'll have to take a recursive approach, cannot be solved with a simple filter etc. Is this JSON structure fixed as you've posted in the question?

Comment: @SivcanSingh Yeah the nest_uid is fixed , the is_selected is hwat I added inorder to create the scenarioa , so basically I want to only show the user the immediate tree , and hide all other

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is indeed the answer here. Something like this should work, even if it's not the prettiest:

```
function selectInJSON(uid, current) {
  current.is_selected = current.nest_uid === uid

  Object.values(current).forEach((child) => {
      if (Array.isArray(child)) {
        child.forEach((item) => {
          selectInJSON(uid, item)
          if (item.is_selected) current.is_selected = true
        })
      }
      else if (Object(child) === child) {
        selectInJSON(uid, child)
        if (child.is_selected) current.is_selected = true
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: will this code make all the other element's false also?

Comment: Is it going to return anything ?

Comment: It modifies the object in place. If you wanted to return it you would have to make it immutable or do a deep clone. If it worked for you don't forget to mark the answer as correct!